# spfx navigation anchor tag has to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, typescript, spfx

I am trying to create a top navigation from sharepoint list and its getting created but the anchor tag needs to be clicked twice. It should get clicked and redirected in first click. Has anyone faced the problem before?

items.forEach((item: ISPList) =>
{
html +=    `<a id=${item.Title} target="_blank" href=${item.NavigationUrl.Url==null?null:item.NavigationUrl.Url}><img src=${item.ImgUrl==null?null:item.ImgUrl.Url}></img> </a>`  ;
});

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute with anchor tag data-interception="off"

Comment: How we can add this to OOTB navigation?